# Multiply defined symbols in Keil (ERROR L76200E)

Tags: c, keil

I'm trying to split my code but I'm facing the multiply defined symbols in Keil because of the function `calculateNmeaChecksum()`...
Those are my two files :

Main.c :

```
#include "main.h"
#include "UART_functions.c"
char checksum;

int main(void)
{
  HAL_Init();
  SystemClock_Config();

  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_SDMMC1_SD_Init();
  MX_TIM5_Init();
  MX_TIM16_Init();
  MX_FATFS_Init();
  MX_SPI1_Init();
  MX_SPI2_Init();
  MX_USART1_UART_Init();

  HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim16);
  
  checksum = calculateNmeaChecksum("$PMTKLOG,456,0,11,31,2,0,0,0,3769,46*48");

  while (1)
  {
  
  }
}
```

UART_functions.c

```
unsigned char calculateNmeaChecksum(const char *s)
{
unsigned char result;
    result = 0;
    s++;            // Skip dollar sign
    while ((*s != '*') && (*s != '\0'))
    result ^= *s++;
    return result;
}
```

I have this error when I try to compile :

```
UART_GPS\UART_GPS.axf: Error: L6200E: Symbol calculateNmeaChecksum multiply defined (by uart_functions.o and main.o).
```

Comment: Can you add the end of your question ?

Comment: checksum should be an unsigned char, not only a char maybe

Comment: Sorry mb i just edited

Comment: @AdrienG. I tried to change into an unsigned char, still not working...

Comment: Try to remove the const in your function parameter

Comment: Not working neither

Comment: Are the two files complete here? Or you just post a part? Show us your uart_function.h too please

Comment: There are only the other functions used in the main function like "MX_GPIO_Init" that are declared too but nothing to do at all with the function ```calculateNmeaChecksum``` which is fully described here in the ```UART_functions.c```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are compiling the function twice, the first time into "uart_functions.o" and the second time into "main.o". And then you link both modules.

In "main.c" you should include just the header file "uart_functions.h" that declares the function prototype:

```c
unsigned char calculateNmeaChecksum(const char *s);
```

BTW, the error message is crystal clear... ;-)